# Proving this expression via mathematical induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have an expression:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n r^i = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

And the stating "assume that r is a real number other than 1, prove the above for every nonnegative integer n as true". So I performed the "basis step" (I used $r = 2$ and $n = 1$):

$$\sum_{i=0}^1 2^i = 2^0 + 2^1 = 1 + 2 = 3$$

$$\frac{1-2^{1+1}}{1-2} = \frac{1-4}{1-2} = \frac{-3}{-1} = 3$$

So now I move onto the "induction step", namely proving $P(n+1)$. Such that:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} r^i = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r} + r^{n+1} = \frac{1-r^{(n+1) + 1}}{1-r}$$

Is my current process correct?

Comment: `So I performed the "basis step" (I used r=2 and n=1)` That only proves the base case for $r=2\,$, but you need to prove it for arbitrary $r$. Hint: it's easier to take $n=0$ as the base case.

Comment: @dxiv Yes I re-did as $n=0$ afterwards. Im more concerned with my inductive step reasoning. First, for all $n$ I substitute $n+1$; then I prove that is the correct equation by adding $r^{n+1}$ to both sides of the equation and if they match, that means I induced correctly...right?

Comment: Yes, that's how the inductive step works. You could maybe make it more clear by writing it as: $$\require{cancel}\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} r^i = \color{blue}{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n} r^i\right)}+r^{n+1} = \color{blue}{\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}} + r^{n+1} = \frac{1 - \cancel{r^{n+1}} + \cancel{r^{n+1}} - r^{(n+1) + 1}}{1-r}$$

Comment: @pstatix  The last line shows that $P (n+1) $ follows from $P (n) $ which you need. The 'proof' needs to be rewritten with all steps/assumptions clearly shown.

Comment: @AnyAD Yes I understand that, just wanted to make sure my "follows" process was correct before diving in further.

Comment: @dxiv Can you elaborate on why you did $\frac{r^{n+1} - r^{n+2}}{1-r}$ rather than $\frac{r^{n+2} - r^{n+1}}{1-r}$? How does the first one even hold true?

Comment: @dxiv Wait I think you did $\frac{(r^{n+1})(1-r)}{1-r}$. Right?

Comment: @pstatix That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your induction step is correct. Nevertheless, we have to exclude not only $r = 1$ but $r = 0 $ as well since $r = 0$ yields in the first term of sum the expression $0^0$ which is undefined (and, as you pointed out in the comment to my unedited answer, the case $r = 0, n = 1$ also does not work).

We want to prove by induction that the following formula holds for any $n \geq 0$ and $r \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \} $
$$ \sum_{i = 0}^n r^i = \frac{1 - r^{n+1}}{1-r} \ .$$

First step of induction: proof for $n = 0$. This holds trivially since 
$$ \sum_{i = 0}^0 r^i = r^0 = 1 = \frac{1 - r}{1-r} \ .$$

Second step (the inductin step): assume that the formula holds for all $k < n$ and proof that then it must hold for $k = n$ as well. We have

$$ \sum_{i = 0}^n r^i = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} (r^i) + r^{n}  \ . $$

Since the first summand on the righ side of the above equality satisfies the formula by assumption, we can expand it accordingly and thus get

$$ \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} (r^i) + r^{n} = \frac{1 - r^n}{1-r} + r^{n}  = \frac{1 - r^n + (1-r)r^n }{1-r}  = \frac{1 - r^{n+1} }{1-r} \ , $$

which was intended to be shown.

Comment: Oddly enough, if you set $r = 0$ and $n = 1$, the LHS and RHS do not equal. You get $0 = 1$. Since $0^1 = 0$ and $\frac{1-0^2}{1-0} = 1$.

Comment: Oh sorry, thanks for the correction.

Comment: To the proposer:  Showing that if the formula holds for all non-negative $k<n$ then  it holds for $k=n $ is called Strong Induction. Showing that (i) the formula holds for $k=0$ and that (ii) if it holds for $k=n-1$ then it holds for $k=n$ is called Weak Induction, Although these are logically equivalent, there are many Q's where Weak  is  easier & clearer, and some deeper Q's  where Strong  is preferred, as using Weak  would require a long  digression .